# Make forecast plot in R from different origins?

Tags: plot, forecasting

I have forecasted data using a rolling technique. Now I want to plot the data to look like this:

https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/cms/asset/71365da7-211e-4247-a524-f9858fc24ec1/mfig001.jpg

That is a classical forecast plot where the forecasted series starts from different origins. How can I make this in an easy way in R? Is it possible to add like "NA" values to the left or, or above, the series?

I mean, I have a dataframe, in row 1 I have forecasts for 8 periods ahead starting from origin 1.
In row 2 I have forecasts for 8 periods ahead starting from origin 2. I think that if I add 1 NA value to the left on the second row, 2 NA values to the left in the third row, etc, and then plot it, it should work? But then How do I add the NA values with a loop for all rows? Is there any other way to achieve such a graph?

Thanks for inspiration.

I am asking for ideas on how to make this in a convenient way, as someone is likely to have done it before me and I have not been able to find example code for this online.

Answer (score 1):

The tidyverse is perfect for this sort of thing:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Synthetic data frame
set.seed(1)
df <- matrix(runif(32), nrow = 4) |> 
  as.data.frame()

# Wrangle data into better form for analysis
df |> 
  mutate(origin = row_number()) |> 
  pivot_longer(-origin, names_to = "horizon", values_to = "forecast") |>
  mutate(
    horizon = parse_integer(str_remove(horizon, "V")),
    time = origin + horizon - 1,
    origin = as.factor(origin)
  ) |> 
  as_tibble() |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = forecast, col = origin)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-01-18 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>